# Is there an erratum in the Bluetooth spec AUX_ADV_IND example?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, crc

The [Bluetooth Core specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=521059) gives, in section 6.C.4.2.2 (p.2909), an example Extended Advertising PDU:

```
PDU:
11100000 00001000 01010010 10010010 01110101 10110101 00110101
11010101 01010101 10010101 00111101 01010111 01101011 10100000
11100000 10010000 11010000 10110000
CRC:
00011011 11000100 01110101
```

This part of the packet is the only part handled by the CRC algorithm defined in Section 6.B.3.1.1, pp.2733–4.  Note that it matches the whitened sequence beneath, without error:

```
$ perl -e '$c=0x71;$a="11100000 00001000 01010010 10010010 01110101 "
   ."10110101 00110101 11010101 01010101 10010101 00111101 01010111 "
   ."01101011 10100000 11100000 10010000 11010000 10110000 00011011 "
   ."11000100 01110101"; for$d(0..length($a)-1){$e=substr($a,$d,1); 
   if($e=~y/01//){$c+=$c;if($c&0x80){$c^=0x91;$e=~y/01/10/;}} 
   print$e;}print"\n";'
00011100 01111110 01111011 11101111 00100101 00000010 10101001
01111001 10010100 00100000 11101100 11000110 01101001 11101101
11011101 01010011 00101000 01011100 01001001 00111110 11010100
```

However I have been unable to regenerate the expected CRC.  As an advertising packet it presets the CRC shift register to the constant `0x555555`, to which the model in CRC RevEng defaults:

```
$ reveng -m crc-24/ble -c 07104a49aeadacabaaa9bcead60507090b0d
a68bc4
```

Expanded to binary, this answer would appear as:

```
01100101 11010001 00100011
```

A single bit flip in the message, `0x07` → `0x27` in the first byte, yields the CRC as stated (here as its hex equivalent):

```
$ reveng -m crc-24/ble -c 27104a49aeadacabaaa9bcead60507090b0d
d823ae
```

But the whitened sequence reinforces the original (or else both are wrong).  Instead a modified Init vector `0x515555` has the same effect as the bit flip, and elicits the given result:

```
$ reveng -m crc-24/ble -i 515555 -c 07104a49aeadacabaaa9bcead60507090b0d
d823ae
```

This constant appears nowhere in the Bluetooth spec, nor is there any sign of how it might be derived.

So, what gives?  Is the Init vector supposed to be `0x515555` in this case? Are both the Spec's copies of the PDU wrong? Or, was the CRC miscalculated in the example?

Comment: The next two examples in that section provide explicit initial CRC values. How about you try getting those to work first?

Comment: Just checked again, no problem with those or the other two (sections 2.1, 4.2.1).

Comment: I confirm the inconsistency in spec. I would not be surprised by an error in the PDU / calculation. 0x515555 as init seems unlikely. You should definitely report to spec authors.

Comment: A step I hadn't considered, but I'd like to see hardware showing the same discrepancy before approaching them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would conclude that yes, there is something awry with that particular example, the second of four. The CRCs of the other three examples in that section check out, using `0x555555` for the first one, and the given initial values for the last two.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Mark, would still like to know whether the PDU or CRC is in error.